# using variable in transfer tag in vxml

Tags: vxml

I am writing a VXML script to execute a Bridge transfer. 
This is how it looks-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml" version="2.0" >

<form id="F1">
<transfer aai="name:Caller1; ANI:94100; myAaiCDATA" name="T_1" bridge="true"     dest="sip:5060@10.130.140.38" >
  <prompt>
    Placing the call
  </prompt>
</transfer>
</form>
</vxml>
```

It completes the transfer successfully.

Now, instead of passing hard-coded values for aai name, ANI, I want to pass on variables. 
For e.g.- I want to pass transfer dest value from a variable.
How can I do that?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/#dml2.3.7), you can set the aii and dest values dynamically with aiiexpr and destexpr.  With these attributes, the value is treated as an ECMAScript expression that is executed with the result value being used.